# Spring boot datasource is down with exception

Tags: mysql, spring, spring-boot

I've setup spring boot so under /health to display the datasource status. However, I'm getting this JSON back:

```
"dataSource" : {
   "status" : "DOWN",
   "database" : "MySQL",
   "error" : "org.springframework.dao.TransientDataAccessResourceException: StatementCallback; SQL [SELECT 1]; Conversion not supported for type java.lang.Object; nested exception is java.sql.SQLException: Conversion not supported for type java.lang.Object"
},
```

As you can see my database is mysql and I'm running it on Windows8. I did try the 'select 1' query and it did return 1 in the command line of mysql. Any idea where the problem might be?

Comment: It works for me with MySQL 5.6.19, mysql-connector-java:5.1.31, and Spring Boot 1.1.4.RELEASE. This was on Mac OS X, though. What versions of the various components that are involved are you using?

Comment: Hi, I just tried with mysql 5.5.37, mysql-connector-java 5.1.31 and spring boot version 1.1.4.RELEASE on linux mint and it failed with the same error. I'll try to update the mysql and post the result here.

Comment: Hi, I am having the same issue using spring boot 1.1.4.RELEASE and MySQL 5.7.2-m12 for Win64 on Windows 8. Everything works but the health is showing this strange error.. :) maybe we need health for health to check is the health working ? :)))

Comment: Interesting, thanks. Two more variables to consider: what version of Java are you using and which connection pool are you using?

Comment: Hi Andy, my java is 1.7.0_40 and connection pool is HikariCP

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`DataSourceHealthIndicator` runs its configured query (`SELECT 1` by default) by calling `JdbcTemplate`:

```java
this.jdbcTemplate.queryForObject(query, Object.class)
```

On Java 6, this ultimately leads to a call to `ResultSet.getObject(index)` and things work as expected. On Java 7, the call is to `ResultSet.getObject(index, Object.class)` (this overload of getObject is new in Java 7). In its default configuration the MySQL JDBC driver is unable to create and return an instance of `java.lang.Object` so it throws the exception described in the question.

You can change MySQL's behaviour and have it return an instance of whatever is appropriate for the column by enabling auto-deserialization:

```
spring.datasource.url: jdbc:mysql://localhost/test?autoDeserialize=true
```

I've also opened [Spring boot issue](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/1306) so that we can make a change so that enabling auto-deserialization isn't necessary.